# what does -0x4(%rbp) means in gdb disassembly?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, disassembly

i am currently working on gdb disassembly to help me understand more detail about the c program so i write a c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int a, int b){
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
}
void main(){
        int a = 1,b = 2;
        swap(a, b);
}
```

I use gdb and run `disass /m main` to get those:

```
(gdb) disass /m main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
8   void main(){
   0x0000000000400492 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400493 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400496 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp

9       int a = 1,b = 2;
   0x000000000040049a <+8>: movl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004a1 <+15>:    movl   $0x2,-0x4(%rbp)

10      swap(a, b);
   0x00000000004004a8 <+22>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
   0x00000000004004ab <+25>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x00000000004004ae <+28>:    mov    %edx,%esi
   0x00000000004004b0 <+30>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0x00000000004004b2 <+32>:    callq  0x400474 <swap>

11  }
   0x00000000004004b7 <+37>:    leaveq 
   0x00000000004004b8 <+38>:    retq   

End of assembler dump.
```

### My question is those `-0x8(%rbp)` means what?

A memory or a register?

I do know that 1 is store in `-0x8(%rbp)` and 2 is in `-0x4(%rbp)`, How can i show the value in
thoes kind of 'place' ?
I try to use `(gdb) p -0x8(%rbp)` but get this:

```
A syntax error in expression, near `%rbp)'.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you want to write `void swap(int *a, int *b)`? Otherwise the change is not reflected to the caller.

Comment: You are right,but this is a demo, i just want to use it to see more detail from the assembly layer.So i can figure out why we should use pointer to change the value!

Comment: If you can't understand AT&T syntax or simply you don't like it, you can tell `GDB` to use Intel's.

`set disassembly-flavor intel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registers in gdb can be referred with the prefix '$'

```
p *(int *)($rbp - 8)
```

RBP and RSP most likely refer to memory locations, specifically to stack. Other registers are more or less generic purpose registers and can point to memory too.

Answer (score 3):

The actually meaning of those structures such as `-0x8(%rbp)` depends on the architecture (or the assembly language). But in this case, `-0x8(%rbp)` is a memory address, probably value of `%rbp` minus 8.

In gdb, you can print the value of those memory address by doing something like

```
info r rbp
p *(int *)(value_of_rbp - 8)
```

Comment: Great! and another question %edx mean memory too?

Comment: @RedWolf'sHusband No, `%edx` means a register named `edx`. For example, `mov  -0x4(%rbp),%edx` means, I guess, moving (copying, actually) the contents in address `%rbp - 4` to register `%edx`.

Answer (score 2):

It means "the data stored when you subtract eight from the address stored in rbp". Try looking at the stack commands available in gdb: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_41.html

Comment: The link now redirects to gnu.org  I don't know how long these links will be around but I found some that can be of use for those who are interested: https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/gdb.html and https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html